# Как получить POST от Callback API Вконтакте? Python

Tags: python, api, вконтакте, callback

Возможно ли получить POST запрос от Callback API Вконтакте?

P.S. Callback API от ВК возвращает JSON на указанный url или ip примерно такого вида:

```
{ "type": "confirmation", "group_id": 140897660 }
```

Как можно принять его в скрипте? Что для этого нужно использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все ответы есть в статье: https://habr.com/post/326898/

Ссылка на гитхаб : https://github.com/strorinWind/bot

token и confirmation_token создать надо в вк,в настройках группы

Напишу здесь,чтобы был нормальный ответ:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processing():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if 'type' not in data.keys():
        return 'not vk'
    if data['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return confirmation_token
    elif data['type'] == 'message_new':
        messageHandler.create_answer(data['object'], token)
        return 'ok' # ok ответ для вк
```